# In Debezium op type is coming as null

Tags: mysql, debezium, connector

I have a Debezium connector upon a MySql DB table. I am adding the `op` type to the payload this way:

```
"transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "op",
```

I am not sure if it is relevant, but I am also filtering the messages by:

```
"transforms.filter.condition": "value.op == 'c' || (value.op == 'u' && value.before.status != value.after.status)"
```

I've noticed that once in a while I am getting messages with `"__op": null` in the payload.
Does anyone have an explanation for why could such a thing happen?